# Confirm some logical inferences for me please?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Sorry, I am just preparing some notes for my students and want to double check I have my facts right before I give the notes to them.
So these are my premises:

1. $\lnot p\rightarrow o$
2. $s\rightarrow r$
3. $\lnot (o\land r)$
4. $\lnot p$

And I want  : $\lnot s$

So, casually, we can get from $\lnot p$ to $o$ using Modus Ponens, proving $o$.

$\lnot(o\land r)$ is the same as $\lnot o\lor\lnot r$.

Using simplification we can assert from this that ¬r is true.

From this we can get to $\lnot s$ using Modus tollens.

Is this correct ? I am tired from writing ~40 pages of notes and am nearly positive I have missed something here.

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: Dave's question seems to be tongue-in-cheek, but there is a serious questions there. You could be using any of several axiomatics. What is an axiom in one is a theorem in the other.

Comment: I'm so happy I'm not in that class and also that I'm clueless about where to find all those characters on my keyboard. Shouldn't this question be better off at math.stackechange.com ?

Comment: you meant $(\neg o \vee \neg r)$

Comment: 40 pages to get to this point?

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: Why did you reintroduce the typo $\neg o\wedge\neg r$ for $\neg o\vee\neg r$?

Comment: @Christian: I assume the correct answer is "by mistake"... :-) I have corrected that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The task is to prove $\neg s$ from the assumptions (1)-(4).

**Proof 1 (by deduction, Modus Ponens):**

These are true facts:

- $\neg p $ by (4)
- $o$ by (1)
- $\neg r$ by (3) in the equivalent form $\neg o \vee \neg r$ (De Morgans's Law), and the proved $o$
- $\neg s$ by (2) in the equivalent form $\neg r \rightarrow \neg s$ (negation of implication) and the proved $\neg r$

**Proof 2 (by contradiction):**

These are true facts:

- $s$ by assumption (negation of $\neg s$ which should be proven)
- $r$ by (2)
- $\neg o$ by (3) in the equivalent form $\neg o \vee \neg r$ (De Morgans's Law) and the proved $r$
- p by (1) in the equivalent form $\neg o \rightarrow p$ (negation of implication) and the proved $\neg o$
- proved $p$ contradicts the fact (4) $\neg p$, hence the assumption $s$ is false and $\neg s$ must true

Answer (score 2):

¬ (o∧r) is NOT the same as (¬o ∧ ¬r), it is the same as (¬o $\lor$ ¬r)  (see [De Morgans's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws))

So here (¬o $\lor$ ¬r) is the equivalent to ¬r since o is true

Then s is false due to the s → r rule.